# Java scheduler to execute method(i.e. task) on Sunday at 4 pm system time

Tags: java, scheduler, java-6

I am new to java world.
Can anyone please help me with sample code of Java scheduler which executes method(i.e. task) on every Sunday at  4 pm System Time ?
Note - I am using jdk 1.6 in my application.

Comment: *jdk 1.6* - why?

Comment: My application has limitation of using jdk1.6 due to various other constraints. So, we have to search solution with jdk1.6 only.